# c++: How can I read double scalar data from a vti grid using the vtk library?

Tags: c++, vtk

I am trying to read the double values from a grid in my vti file. However, the return value I get from `GetScalarPointer` generates a segmentation fault when I try to access any element inside of it, e.g. with `scalarPtr[0]`:

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkXMLImageDataReader.h>
#include <vtkImageData.h>

int main(){
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLImageDataReader> reader =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLImageDataReader>::New();
  reader->SetFileName("my_file.vti");
  reader->Update();
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> imageData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::Take(reader->GetOutput());
  double* scalarPtr = static_cast<double*>(imageData->GetScalarPointer());
  std::cout << scalarPtr[0] << std::endl; // segmentation fault
}
```

I know the type is double because `imageData->GetDataType()` returns 11, which corresponds to `VTK_DOUBLE`.

I also tried to see if it was due to the endianness of the values, but

```
double* scalarPtr = static_cast<double*>(imageData->GetScalarPointer());
const vtkIdType numScalars = imageData->GetNumberOfPoints();
const int scalarSize = sizeof(double);
vtkByteSwap::SwapVoidRange(scalarPtr, numScalars, scalarSize);
```

also results in a segmentation fault, probably because `scalarPtr` is not accessible.

These are the contents of my `vtkImageData` class:

```
vtkImageData (0x556e1ad5afd0)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 307
  Reference Count: 1
  Registered Events: (none)
  Information: 0x556e1ad5b470
  Data Released: False
  Global Release Data: Off
  UpdateTime: 0
  Field Data:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 307
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Number Of Arrays: 1
    Array 0 name = comments
    Number Of Components: 1
    Number Of Tuples: 1
  Number Of Points: 2431
  Number Of Cells: 1920
  Cell Data:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 302
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events:
      Registered Observers:
        vtkObserver (0x556e1ad5cb00)
          Event: 33
          EventName: ModifiedEvent
          Command: 0x556e1ad5c6a0
          Priority: 0
          Tag: 1
    Number Of Arrays: 1
    Array 0 name = material
    Number Of Components: 1
    Number Of Tuples: 1920
    Copy Tuple Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 )
    Interpolate Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 )
    Pass Through Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 )
    Scalars: (none)
    Vectors: (none)
    Normals: (none)
    TCoords: (none)
    Tensors: (none)
    GlobalIds: (none)
    PedigreeIds: (none)
    EdgeFlag: (none)
    Tangents: (none)
    RationalWeights: (none)
    HigherOrderDegrees: (none)
  Point Data:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 304
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events:
      Registered Observers:
        vtkObserver (0x556e1ad5c8e0)
          Event: 33
          EventName: ModifiedEvent
          Command: 0x556e1ad5c6a0
          Priority: 0
          Tag: 1
    Number Of Arrays: 0
    Number Of Components: 0
    Number Of Tuples: 0
    Copy Tuple Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 )
    Interpolate Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 )
    Pass Through Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 )
    Scalars: (none)
    Vectors: (none)
    Normals: (none)
    TCoords: (none)
    Tensors: (none)
    GlobalIds: (none)
    PedigreeIds: (none)
    EdgeFlag: (none)
    Tangents: (none)
    RationalWeights: (none)
    HigherOrderDegrees: (none)
  Bounds:
    Xmin,Xmax: (0, 5e-06)
    Ymin,Ymax: (0, 8e-06)
    Zmin,Zmax: (0, 6e-06)
  Compute Time: 308
  Spacing: (5e-07, 5e-07, 5e-07)
  Origin: (0, 0, 0)
  Direction: (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
  Dimensions: (11, 17, 13)
  Increments: (0, 0, 0)
  Extent: (0, 10, 0, 16, 0, 12)
```

What am I doing wrong in terms of how I am accessing the grid values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to select the correct XML nesting level, which was ImageData -> CellData -> DataArray:

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkXMLImageDataReader.h>
#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtkCellData.h>
#include <vtkIntArray.h>

int main(){
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLImageDataReader> reader =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLImageDataReader>::New();
  reader->SetFileName("my_file.vti");
  reader->Update();

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> imageData = reader->GetOutput();
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellData> cellData = imageData->GetCellData();
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArray> dataArray = cellData->GetArray("material");

  int dims[3];
  imageData->GetDimensions(dims);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) dims[i] = dims[i]-1;

  for (int k = 0; k <= dims[2]; k++) {
      for (int j = 0; j <= dims[1]; j++) {
          for (int i = 0; i <= dims[0]; i++) {
              double value = dataArray->GetComponent(
                  i + j * dims[0] + k * dims[0] * dims[1], 0);
              std::cout << "Value at (" << i << ", " << j << ", " << k << "): " 
                        << value << std::endl;
          }
      }
  }
}
```